# Angular ui-select multiple hide selected

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-select, angularjs-1.6

Is it possible to hide some SELECTED items in `ng-select` multiple select?

I create event with multiple users, including myself. I want to keep myself on the list in model but I don't want to display myself in ui-select-match.

I've tried using `ng-hide` on `ui-select-match`, but it was unsuccessful.

```
<ui-select multiple ng-model="event.users" theme="bootstrap">
   <ui-select-match placeholder="Select users...">{$ $item.username $}</ui-select-match>
   <ui-select-choices repeat="user in users">
      <div ng-bind-html="user.username" ng-show="user.id != auth.id"></div>
   </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Comment: Can you make a Fiddle of your code?

Comment: sure, http://jsfiddle.net/2av2eps8/1/

Comment: I don't know how you can **hide** it, but you can forbide deleting yourself with: `ui-lock-choice="$item.id == auth.id"`: http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/aL6kwmtv/

Comment: Ok, that's good enough for now, thank you :) @Mistalis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you can hide it, but you can forbide deleting yourself with:

```
ui-lock-choice="$item.id == auth.id"
```

### [Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/aL6kwmtv)